# Stripe Webhooks Testing in Go

Tags: go, testing, stripe-payments

How can I mock the requests from Stripe to my webhooks with Stripe's Go library?

The Node library has the `stripe.webhooks.generateTestHeaderString` method that allows to mock such requests:

```js
const payload = {
  id: 'evt_test_webhook',
  object: 'event',
};

const payloadString = JSON.stringify(payload, null, 2);
const secret = 'whsec_test_secret';

const header = stripe.webhooks.generateTestHeaderString({
  payload: payloadString,
  secret,
});

const event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payloadString, header, secret);

// Do something with mocked signed event
expect(event.id).to.equal(payload.id);
```

However, I do not see such method on the `webhook` package.

Is there any way we can achieve the same with the Go library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new `GenerateTestSignedPayload` function (in the [webhook package](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/tree/master/webhook)) has been added with the [Stripe Go SDK version v73.1.0](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/releases/tag/v73.1.0), see [PR #1520](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/pull/1520). This provides similar functionality to Stripe Node SDK's `generateTestHeaderString`.

The [Testing Webhook signing section](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/master/README.md#testing-webhook-signing) in the `README` provides an example on how to use it:

```
signedPayload := webhook.GenerateTestSignedPayload(&webhook.UnsignedPayload{Payload: payloadBytes, Secret: testSecret})
event, err := webhook.ConstructEvent(signedPayload.Payload, signedPayload.Header, signedPayload.Secret)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Stripe Go SDK doesn't support mocking Webhook. You can either implement one yourself referencing [the Node implementation](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/lib/Webhooks.js#L52), or use a [separated mock server](https://github.com/stripe-ruby-mock/stripe-ruby-mock#mocking-webhooks) (stripe-ruby-mock) that supports webhook mocking.

Context from this [stripe-mock issue](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-mock/issues/16).

Comment: It seems to be the case at the moment, unfortunately :(